# Creating Subgroups based on Time Period using Lubridate and Dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

This should be a quick and easy question. Using the simple dataframe below, I want to use dplyr and lubridate to group all the clients who have an OnsetDate on or after April, 2015. This group would be called "NewOnset" and the remainder will be "OldOnset".

I'm new to lubridate and having some trouble.

```
City<-c("Toronto", "Toronto", "Montreal","Ottawa","Ottawa",
        "Hamilton","Peterborough","Toronto","Hamilton","Hamilton")

OnsetDate<-c("11/04/1980","04/08/2005","04/19/2015","07/10/2015","10/10/1999","03/11/2016","09/12/2011","06/10/2015","02/05/1988","08/08/2016")

Client<-c("Cl1","Cl2","Cl3","Cl4","Cl5","Cl6","Cl7","Cl8","Cl9","Cl10")

DF<- data.frame(Client,City,OnsetDate)
```

Comment: `DF %>% mutate(OnsetDate = as.Date(OnsetDate, '%m/%d/%Y')) %>% group_by(group = if_else(OnsetDate > as.Date('2015-04-01'), 'NewOnset', 'OldOnset'))` or substitute `lubridate::mdy` for `as.Date`

Comment: Thanks! I can give you credit if you make it an official answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With dplyr,

```
       # parse OnsetDate to Date; alternatively use lubridate::mdy(OnsetDate)
DF %>% mutate(OnsetDate = as.Date(OnsetDate, '%m/%d/%Y')) %>% 
    # add and group by new column
    group_by(group = if_else(OnsetDate >= as.Date('2015-04-01'),    # condition
                             'NewOnset',    # return if above (true)
                             'OldOnset'))   # return if below (false)

## Source: local data frame [10 x 4]
## Groups: group [2]
## 
##    Client         City  OnsetDate    group
##    <fctr>       <fctr>     <date>    <chr>
## 1     Cl1      Toronto 1980-11-04 OldOnset
## 2     Cl2      Toronto 2005-04-08 OldOnset
## 3     Cl3     Montreal 2015-04-19 NewOnset
## 4     Cl4       Ottawa 2015-07-10 NewOnset
## 5     Cl5       Ottawa 1999-10-10 OldOnset
## 6     Cl6     Hamilton 2016-03-11 NewOnset
## 7     Cl7 Peterborough 2011-09-12 OldOnset
## 8     Cl8      Toronto 2015-06-10 NewOnset
## 9     Cl9     Hamilton 1988-02-05 OldOnset
## 10   Cl10     Hamilton 2016-08-08 NewOnset
```

Note the grouping here doesn't *do* anything, and you could do both operations in `mutate`, but you do get a grouped data.frame appropriate for further mutation or summarization.

An alternative would be to use `cut.Date`, which will return a factor:

```
# parse OnsetDate to Date; alternatively use lubridate::mdy(OnsetDate)
DF %>% mutate(OnsetDate = as.Date(OnsetDate, '%m/%d/%Y')) %>% 
    # add and group by new column
    group_by(group = cut(OnsetDate, 
                         breaks = c(min(OnsetDate), as.Date('2015-04-01'), max(OnsetDate)), 
                         labels = c('OldOnset', 'NewOnset'), 
                         include.lowest = TRUE))

## Source: local data frame [10 x 4]
## Groups: group [2]
## 
##    Client         City  OnsetDate    group
##    <fctr>       <fctr>     <date>   <fctr>
## 1     Cl1      Toronto 1980-11-04 OldOnset
## 2     Cl2      Toronto 2005-04-08 OldOnset
## 3     Cl3     Montreal 2015-04-19 NewOnset
## 4     Cl4       Ottawa 2015-07-10 NewOnset
## 5     Cl5       Ottawa 1999-10-10 OldOnset
## 6     Cl6     Hamilton 2016-03-11 NewOnset
## 7     Cl7 Peterborough 2011-09-12 OldOnset
## 8     Cl8      Toronto 2015-06-10 NewOnset
## 9     Cl9     Hamilton 1988-02-05 OldOnset
## 10   Cl10     Hamilton 2016-08-08 NewOnset
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to use external package to do this easy task. In base R:

```
## coerce character to a valid date
DF$OnsetDate <- as.Date(DF$OnsetDate ,"%m/%d/%Y")
## flter rows
DF[DF$OnsetDate>"2015-04-30",]

#    Client     City  OnsetDate
# 4     Cl4   Ottawa 2015-07-10
# 6     Cl6 Hamilton 2016-03-11
# 8     Cl8  Toronto 2015-06-10
# 10   Cl10 Hamilton 2016-08-08
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without dplyr functionality. Lubridate's family of functions are named by the format of the object you're converting to a date. In this case, you want to use the `mdy` function, since the input format is in month-day-year.

`DF$OnsetDate <- mdy(DF$OnsetDate)`

Then you can create your new dataframes by subsetting the rows based on your criteria.

```
NewOnset <- DF[DF$OnsetDate >= as.Date("2015-04-01"), ]
OldOnset <- DF[DF$OnsetDate < as.Date("2015-04-01"), ]
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of issues with your code. This should fix it:

```
City <- c("Toronto", "Toronto", "Montreal", "Ottawa", "Ottawa", "Hamilton", "Peterborough", "Toronto", "Hamilton", "Hamilton")
OnsetDate <- c("11/04/1980","04/08/2005","04/19/2015","07/10/2015","10/10/1999","03/11/2016","09/12/2011","06/10/2015","02/05/1988","08/08/2016")
Client <- c("Cl1","Cl2","Cl3","Cl4","Cl5","Cl6","Cl7","Cl8","Cl9","Cl10")

df <- data.frame(Client, City, OnsetDate)

df$OnsetDate <- as.Date(df$OnsetDate, format = "%m/%d/%Y")    

# here comes the magic
df %>% filter(OnsetDate > as.Date("04/01/2015", format = "%m/%d/%Y"))
```

You can use the `format` parameter, and there's no real need for the `lubridate` package here. The above code yields:

```
  Client     City  OnsetDate
1    Cl3 Montreal 2015-04-19
2    Cl4   Ottawa 2015-07-10
3    Cl6 Hamilton 2016-03-11
4    Cl8  Toronto 2015-06-10
5   Cl10 Hamilton 2016-08-08
```